# How to catch .net remoting calls and check thread on client side?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, remoting

I have a client-server application. They are communicates with each other with [.NET Remoting (4.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Server is the service, and client is WPF UI application. Sometimes calls to the server perform on UI thread. It is bad practice, because UI will freeze if some delay take place. I want to prevent such

So I would like to add a global validator (for example in debug mode) for each remoting call:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void CheckNotUIThread()
{
    if (System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Remoting call on UI thread");
}
```

So I wonder where can I catch remoting call on the client side in order to validate the thread?

**Edit:**

The objects that server returns particularly all derived from **[MarshalByRefObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**. Other objects are POCO, or its combination, marked as [Serializable].

Comment: Why are you using Remoteing in a WPF project, did you see the big bold text on the first line of the page you linked? "***This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development.***" EDIT: after reading your response to antistar's answer it looks like you are writing a new client for an existing application.

Comment: Yes, I saw. I told about it to our architect a lot of time.  The answer - currently the system is large, and there is no time to move it to WCF. And yes, we have only server API, and we develop WPF UI client using that one.

Answer (score 2):

you can extend RealProxy class and intercept remoting calls. 
Please check this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/geoffda/archive/2007/11/07/using-a-custom-proxy-for-interception.aspx

Comment: The big disadvantage of this method is that it is requires to code the common API both for server and client. I have no access to change that API - I can only get the objects. The next one is that [Applying the proxy attribute to a child of MarshalByRefObject is not supported.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scx1w94y(v=vs.100).aspx). As far as the server I use returns **MarshalByRefObject**, this is not the case.